# Alert box not working in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

This is my **contact-form-handler.php** file. After clicking submit button, I want an alert in PHP. I am receiving Mail successfully and redirect to my main page but without an alert message. How can I use the alert box in PHP?

My form is working fine, but this time I stucked in this simple task.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //$companyMail = 'enesh@gmail.com';
        $to = "eneshpal@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
        $customerMail = $_POST['formEmail']; // this is the sender's Email address
        $first_name = $_POST['formFirstName'];
        $last_name = $_POST['formLastName'];
        $phone = $_POST['formPhone'];
        $text = $_POST['formText'];
        /* foreach($_POST['project_type'] as $project_type_value){} */
        $projectType = implode(', ',$_POST['project_type']);
        $scopeProject = implode(', ',$_POST['scope_project']);
        $project_type_Str = 'Project Type : '.$projectType;
        $scope_project_Str = 'Scope of Project : '.$scopeProject;
        $subject = "Form Submission";
        $message = "Hi, \n\n";
        $message .= "First Name: ".$first_name . "\nLast Name: " . $last_name . " \nEmail: " . $customerMail . " \nPhone : " . $phone . "\nDescription: " . $text . "\n";
        $message .=  $project_type_Str."\n";
        $message .= $scope_project_Str;
        //$message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
        //$headers = "From:" . $companyMail;
        //$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
        if(mail($to,$subject,$message)){
            //echo 'Mail Sent';
            //$message = "Thanks, We Will Contact you Shortly";
            //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
            echo "<script>alert('Thanks, We Will Contact you Shortly');</script>";
            header('Location:get_estimation.php');
        }else{
            echo 'Mail Not Sent';
        }
        //mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
        /*if( "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.")
        else die; */
        // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
```

Comment: That's because you use `header`... Opt for redirecting the user via Javascript instead.

Comment: Why do you want to use an alert box specifically? Or do you mean you just wish to render a success message after the form has been submitted?

Comment: Yes Sir I want just just wish to render a success message after the form has been submitted?

Comment: @Ginni I have given you a full and complete answer. If it resolves your issue please mark as accepted answer and also upvote, if you can. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your script, but to answer your key question... you are `echo`'ing out the javascript code for an `alert()`, which will in turn prevent your php `header('Location:get_estimation.php');` from executing because there has already been output sent to the browser before `header` was called. [See here for more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

As per your comment above...

> Yes Sir I want just just wish to render a success message after the form has been submitted?

To give you an example of how to achieve what you need for this...

---

```
<?php

if (!empty($_GET['success'])) {
    echo 'Thanks, we will contact you shortly';
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "eneshpal@gmail.com";
    $customerMail = $_POST['formEmail'];
    $first_name = $_POST['formFirstName'];
    $last_name = $_POST['formLastName'];
    $phone = $_POST['formPhone'];
    $text = $_POST['formText'];
    $projectType = implode(', ', $_POST['project_type']);
    $scopeProject = implode(', ', $_POST['scope_project']);

    $project_type_Str = 'Project Type : ' . $projectType;
    $scope_project_Str = 'Scope of Project : ' . $scopeProject;

    $subject = "Form Submission";

    $message = "Hi, \n\n";
    $message .= "First Name: " . $first_name . "\nLast Name: " . $last_name . " \nEmail: " . $customerMail . " \nPhone : " . $phone . "\nDescription: " . $text . "\n";
    $message .= $project_type_Str . "\n";
    $message .= $scope_project_Str;

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message)) {
        header('Location: get_estimation.php?success=1');
        exit;
    } else {
        echo 'Mail Not Sent';
        exit;
    }
}
```

---

To explain, you should not be using a browser-native javascript `alert` rendered from php to pop-up and notify the user of a form submission success, especially immediately after a redirect. It's just a bad user experience, it hijacks the browser window until they click ok on it and you cannot really style native alert windows etc.

Instead you should redirect with a success `GET` variable after the mail is sent successfully (back to the original page, presuming that is `get_estimation.php` in my example - but you can redirect elsewhere to another script). Then you can detect the presence of this variable in the script redirected to and show an appropriate message etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it would be better to redirect the user

```
header('Location:get_estimation.php?success=true');
```

and pass a GET-parameter.

When the GET-Parameter is set it will display what you want on your get_estimation.php-page

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Thank You,will contact you soon";
echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'get_estimation.php';\",3000); </script>";
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine, Can you help me for jQuery form validation in php.

Comment: Validation in the sense?input box should accept only letters or only numbers or both?or any regular expressions?

Comment: Check out this blog for validating and accepting only numbers,alphabets https://akhilreddyyalla.blogspot.in/2018/01/how-to-restrict-input-box-to-accept_75.html